# eCompass of BQ Aquaris e5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq

The specification of BQ E5 Ubuntu edition says there would be an *eCompass*.

See Section *Sensors* on the following page:

http://www.bq.com/gb/aquaris-e5-ubuntu-edition

The compass does not work with the application *Cachemere* and the application *SensorsData* says *No data available* on page *Compass*.

Nevertheless, in the system file

`/sys/devices/platform/msensor/driver/chipinfo`

one can read:

`mmc3516x Chip`

This is a magnetic field sensor according to http://www.memsic.com/magnetic-sensors/MMC3316xMT and should provide the compass function.

So I assume that the device is technically able to work as a compass.

1. **Is there already an application that allows one to use the phone as a compass?**
2. **If there is none yet can the compass be read-out via the device-orientation event (see http://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/)?**

Looks like others have the same problem:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2283890

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have posted the compass to the store. However, to use it You have to install the open store. It breaks the app armor by reading device file...

https://open.uappexplorer.com/app/compass.kwek